# sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

We have an oracle database and i am trying to connect to oracle database using python in linux. We have installed "sqlalchemy" , "cx_Oracle" libraries.

When i try to execute the below python script, i am getting below error.

```
Error: sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1047: 
Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open 
shared object file: No such file or directory". See 
https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)
```

Is there any way without installing "Instant Client" , i can connect to oracle database and execute .... ?

Please help me with any suggestion

Below is the code.

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import types,create_engine

conn = create_engine('oracle://User:password@hostname:1521/?service_name=ABCD') 

cur = conn

ABC = []

select = cur.execute("select EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME from EMPLOYEE") 
for line in select:
    ABC.append(line)

print(ABC)
```

Comment: You need Oracle Client libraries.  On machines with no Oracle software, the easiest option is to install Oracle Instant Client, see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-linux

Comment: @ChristopherJones. Thanks a lot for the reply. In my linux server we do have Oracle server but instant client we dont have prevalence to install. But without instant client is that possible ? Please help

Comment: The installation instructions show how to use the scenario you have.

Comment: @Arya Were you able to fix this ?